# What's the order of execution of commands in bash?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've made a little command that is supposed to `cd` me to subdirectory with the name of current date, and if such directory doesn't exist, firstly creates one:

`cd $(date +%F) || (mkdir $(date +%F); cd $(date +%F);)`

It works correctly with pre-existing directory, but when directory doesn't exist it creates the directory but doesn't `cd` :

```
luk45s5@DESKTOP:~/test$ ls                                                                          
luk45s5@DESKTOP:~/test$ cd $(date +%F) || (mkdir $(date +%F); cd $(date +%F);)                      
-bash: cd: 2020-04-04: No such file or directory                                                            
luk45s5@DESKTOP:~/test$ ls                                                                          
2020-04-04
```

What's the problem, how do I fix it? I'm using Ubuntu WSL if that's any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the problem, how do I fix it?

If `cd` fails it will execute the next command which is `mkdir` and `cd` but because of the subshell after the script/commands exit you will be in the same directory where you started the script/commands.

You can use a loop.

```sh
until cd "$(date +%F)" 2>/dev/null; do
  mkdir -p "$(date +%F)"
done
```

In your example you can use command grouping using the `{ }`

```sh
cd $(date +%F) 2>/dev/null || { mkdir $(date +%F) && cd $(date +%F) ; }
```

- `2>/dev/null` redirects the error message to `/dev/null`